# Missing Dependency from rsconnect when deploying shinyapps

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

So i just had a error in Rstudio when i wanted to deploy my apps to shinyapps.io

```
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1319228024 error: Unhandled Exception: Missing dependency 'renv' for package 'rsconnect'
Execution halted
```

i tried to reinstall rsconnect but it still didn't work and I also tried to deploy with different project but the same problem still occurred.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same since I updated the rsconnect package

Answer (score 0):

We have uncovered a problem with projects that have an explicit dependency on renv, as tracked here: https://github.com/rstudio/rsconnect/issues/916

You should be able to avoid this by using packrat for dependency analysis:

```r
options(rsconnect.packrat = TRUE)
```

Alternatively, install the previous version of rsconnect from CRAN:

```r
remotes::install_version("rsconnect", "0.8.29")
```